# 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing

Tags: java, maven

Trying to get familiar with maven and taking an online course and am stuck .... appreciate any help provided.

I'm running the Site phase and although it completes and I'm able to actually view index.html in a browser I am getting a lot of errors along the way, specifically:

'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing

Have no idea why it's generating this error.  As you can see below I have the version in both dependency and plugins.  And I tried all I can find on sites.  Why does it think the version is missing?  Any ideas how to resolve?  thanks in advance for any help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dp</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestNG77</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </dependency>


                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.22.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.7.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>

            <reporting>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </reporting>
```

Comment: Since you have a single project, you don't need **pluginManagement**. Just declare the plugins directly under build. `<build><plugins><plugin>......</plugin></plugins></build>` and then try.

Comment: As @Ramu already showed defining plugins as dependencies is nor necessary nor correct. Furthermore can you create an example project on GitHub.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the following 2 dependencies from `<dependencies>` should fix all the errors. These 2 are maven plugins and not required in `<dependencies>` section.

When you include these 2 as dependencies, `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` is trying to generate dependency report for these 2 plugins and failing. Hence you are seeing those errors.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks Ramu!

Comment: Some clarification @Ramu if you have time.  Any idea why mvnRepository wraps plugin's as dependencies?  Seems misleading but I'm sure there is a good reason

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>